# How to prevent View above the keyboard (adjustResize)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

My layout has the following structure:

[image]

In the manifest I have an attribute that defines the behavior of the keyboard display after the user clicked on the EditText, which is contained in the ScrollView:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Here is `btnApply` markup:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btnApply"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#00bbe3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="15dip"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="23.75sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So, `btnApply` floats above the keyboard on top of the `ScrollView`, and I can scroll all of the EditText's if they don't fit on the screen.

Is it possible to make `btnApply` doesn't pop up above the keyboard and was pressed to the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

try to change

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

moreover you dont need to put editText in scrollView.

You can just simply add

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

to your editText

cheers